# Parsing <meta itemprop="a" content="b"> with PHP (not in HEAD)

Tags: php, parsing

I need to parse some html code that looks like this:

```html
<div id="item-1" class="genclass" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
    <meta itemprop="isbn" content="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Neverending Story" />
    <meta itemprop="author" content="Michael Ender" />
    <meta itemprop="publisher" content="MyBooks" />
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="1991" />
    <h2 itemprop="offers" itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="6.6" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    </h2>
</div>
```

So I'm trying:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
foreach($dom->find("meta[itemprop='isbn']") as $books){
    switch ($books->itemprop) {
        case 'isbn':
        $line['isbn'] = $books->content;
        break;
    case 'name':
        $line['name'] =  $books->content;
        break;
    case 'author':
        $line['author'] =  $books->content;
        break;
    case 'publisher':
        $line['publisher'] =  $books->content;
        break;
    case 'datePublished':
        $line['datePublished'] =  $books->content;
        break;
    case 'price':
        $line['price'] =  $books->content;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
print_r($books);
```

But the result is always blank. What am I doing wrong? I've tried with get_meta_tags and others...

Comment: Why not grab the div, then look at each `<meta>` tag within the div? Starting with the isbn like you're doing makes little sense to me, and is obviously never going to give you the name or author, etc. because you're only looking at the isbn line.

Comment: there's no `->find()` method under DOMDocument, i think you're mixing `simple-html-dom` with dom